# Word for someone who prepares reports

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms

The situation I am thinking of is where someone within a company runs queries on a database and formats the information (with or without commentary) into a report.

Is there a single word that describes such a person?

I was originally thinking [*reporter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reporter) but that seems too tied to the profession: a reporter is a type of journalist who researches and presents information in certain types of mass media.

The word [*analyst*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyst) seems to cover the *with commentary* part, but I would like to see if there is something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The field in which someone runs database queries is [data analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_analysis):

> Analysis of data is a process of inspecting, cleaning, transforming, and modeling data with the goal of highlighting useful information, suggesting conclusions, and supporting decision making. Data analysis has multiple facets and approaches, encompassing diverse techniques under a variety of names, in different business, science, and social science domains.

A person in such a field is a *data analyst*. That is, they figure out which data is relevant and then run queries.

Comment: Actually, they usually figure out what information is relevant first, and then write the query to extract that information.

Answer (score 4):

The official EU word is *rapporteur*, which possibly confirms that there is a problem with this word. However, as a report is normally the end result of a process of research or analysis, I would say *researcher* or *analyst* depending on usage in the context.

Answer (score 3):

[*Collator*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/collator) might be usable, although it's rare.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could call the person a ["researcher":](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Researcher)

> A researcher is somebody who performs research, the search for knowledge or in general any systematic investigation to establish facts. Researchers can work in academic, industrial, government, or private institutions.

The results of a research are then written up into a report, with a title, aim, discussion, and conclusions.